# reading Memory-Mapped IO registers How to (from datasheet) and using them in mmap

Tags: c, driver, x86-64, kali-linux, memory-mapped-io

I have intel system with `Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) (rev 04)`. I have downloaded the datasheet like datasheet for `Intel ® 82579 Gigabit Ethernet PHY`

Now I am reading resource0 of pci ethernet device like

```
    if((fd = open("/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:19.0/resource1", O_RDWR | O_SYNC)) == -1) {
        perror("Error: open error");
    }

    int map_size = 4096UL;
    ...
    map_base = mmap(0,4096UL , PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, Register_Values_From_Datasheet);
```

I have x86-64 bit system. kali linux 5.7.
so I am substituting  `Register_Values_From_Datasheet`from above with register offset values from datasheet like `0x00008` for `STATUS:Device Status Register`=from datasheet

but errno of mmap() is having value `22:EINVAL` after mmap call. Means invalid argument. Maybe the offset values that I am reading from datasheet may have to be interpreted some other way.

My resource file in sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:19.0 of Ethernet device is something like this

```
        0x00000000fe400000 0x00000000fe41ffff 0x0000000000040200
        0x00000000fe427000 0x00000000fe427fff 0x0000000000040200
        0x000000000000f060 0x000000000000f07f 0x0000000000040101
        0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
        0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
        0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
        0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
        0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
        0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
        0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
        0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
        0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
        0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
```

As from above dump of resource text file (resource0) shows my Memory-Mapped IO starts at 0x00000000fe400000. So that I think should be the return address of mmap (return (void*)=&0x00000000fe400000)= but I am getting something like `0xffffffff` and errno is 22. Can any one guide me in the right direction as to how the offset needs to be interpreted from datasheet. Also which registers normally need to be accessed for getting packets for pci Ethernet device. Since I am new to device programming.

Comment: are you getting the same results with `MAP_PRIVATE`

Comment: The offset needs to be a multiple of the page size (4096).

Comment: @IanAbbott Still error:errno=22. I am doing it like `map_base = mmap(0,4096UL , PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0x00008*4096UL);`  0x00008 is the offset value of Status register in the datasheet:Device Status Register

Comment: @IanAbbott can errno:22 be due to access rights?

Comment: Problems with access rights usually result in EACCES, which is probably errno 13 on your system.

Comment: Did you make sure the Linux kernel's own drivers didn't already "claim" this MMIO region?  i.e. unload the `e1000e` module or whatever.  Check `lspci -v` and look for `Kernel driver in use: <name>` for that PCI device.

Comment: @PeterCordes e1000e is in use. so u are saying multiple modules or programs cant access MMIO region at same time? Also how about the answer by @(Halt State) he says I have to look for register inside the region  as offsets in datasheets are offset into region. if thats the case how can I get the size of region [is 32*4096 is the size of first region?so I have to look into second or other regions (to move over first resource 0) since resource0 contains list of resources,i.e resource0,resourec1,resource2...resourceN]

Comment: @PeterCordes I have used `rmmod e1000e` but mmap still giving me errno 22

Comment: I don't know if a driver reservation would stop a user-space mmap, but it seemed worth a try because it's certainly possible.

Comment: @PeterCordes I want to debug `mmap` using kprobe and see the inner debug info of the syscall `mmap`. The problem is when I do `cat /proc/kallsyms | grep do_fork` it gives me many routines I dont know which one I should debug. Do u know which kernal routine I should debug with kprobe for `mmap` so I can get to know what's going on behind the scene

Comment: I'd guess that `sys_mmap` would be a better bet, but no, I haven't used kprobes and don't know anything about it.

Comment: @PeterCordes do u mean ` __x64_sys_mmap` OR `__ia32_sys_mmap` ?first one starts at `ffffffffa3631170 T` and second=ia32 one starts at `ffffffffa36311b0 T`?
`

Comment: Obviously that depends on whether you're calling the 64-bit syscall or the 32-bit compat version from 32-bit user-space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in kernel function **iomem_is_exclusive** check **IS_ENABLED(CONFIG_IO_STRICT_DEVMEM)** or **IORESOURCE_EXCLUSIVE** flag is set:

```
        if (IS_ENABLED(CONFIG_IO_STRICT_DEVMEM)
                || p->flags & IORESOURCE_EXCLUSIVE) {
            err = true;
            break;
        }
```

we can simply use **stap** to pass through the check for test:

```
stap -g -e 'probe kernel.function("iomem_is_exclusive").return { $return = 0 }'
```

Comment: does this mean by running this command `stap -g -e 'probe kernel.function("iomem_is_exclusive").return { $return = 0 }'` my code will start working

Comment: I believe stap command related to ebpf is it right. also see my last comment

Answer (score 1):

Resource0 is the list of resources, the remaining Resource1 .. ResourceN are the actual memory regions where the registers are.
(Ref: https://techpubs.jurassic.nl/manuals/linux/developer/REACTLINUX_PG/sgi_html/ch07.html )

The offsets are offsets INTO a region, not offsets of the region.

So you would typically map the entire space of region1 - in your case 128KB because: `0x00000000fe41ffff - 0x00000000fe400000` . (you could also check /proc/iomem for confirmation)

```
map_base = mmap(0,32*4096UL , PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

EDIT:
mmap's signature is:

```
void *mmap(void *addr, size_t length, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset);
```

If you specify a length or offset that exceeds the filesize, you get EINVAL:
From Linux man page:

```
EINVAL We don't like addr, length, or offset (e.g., they are too large, or not aligned on a page boundary).
```

You'd probably end up casting map_base into an array of uint32_t (if all registers are 32 bit) and using:  `map_base_as_int[8/4]` to index into the register space.

The first hurdle is getting read-only data (eg, MAC addresses, and the like).

Once you actually want to send and receive packets, you'll need physical addresses - DPDK code handles this (in a rather complex way), but you can slice out physical memory with GRUB parameters and safely use it ....

---

An alternate approach is to use mmap on '/dev/mem' using the offset from above `fe400000`)
You'll need this for the physical memory accesses later anyway (and you need to ensure your kernel is compiled for access - some locked down kernels aren't)

Comment: is `32*4096` that how big is resource0 address space? please clarify when u did `32*4096` does it mean u will enter in resourec1,etc. and access specific register at offset from datasheets

Comment: Can u please take a look at this question I have asked link question on  this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65642626/need-to-debug-mmap-so-where-is-the-object-file-for-mmap-or-module-containing-mma

Comment: `map_base = mmap(0,4096UL , PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 32*4096); ` errno still 22. no difference. Do I need to map to specific register from datasheet like `32*4096UL+0x00008` 
0x00008 is offset address of some register in datasheet

Comment: My fault, I misled you - the last parameter should be _0_  not 32*4096.  I'll edit my response

Comment: apparently I think the problem is my e1000e device driver ethernet is without implementation of MMAP functionality. this question is related to this link question I asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65749351/in-order-to-write-pci-ethernet-driver-how-to-implement-mmap-in-the-pci-ethernet

Comment: If you can't mmap on the ethernet driver itself, you can mmap( `/dev/mem` ).

Comment: so if I implement mmap in driver now then will I able to mmap on device driver like opening e1000e and mmap on it