# need to debug MMAP so where is the object file for MMAP or module containing MMAP() -- how to find in linux?

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-module, mmap, kprobe

I am trying to debug MMAP with kprobe but I dont know  how to set break points inside MMAP. In my lib/modules there I searched but could not find that resembles mmap containing module. how can I debug mmap with kprobe so I need object file of the routine.

I just need to set breakpoints at different locations. So I could use radare2 for this to view the assembly and check the memory locations which I will specify in KProbe module that will be injected in MMAP function in the routine containing MMAP function, for debugging it.

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps you, but you can set a `struct kprobe`'s `symbol_name` and `offset` fields instead of passing an address. You'd still need to ensure that the offset is sane (i.e. not halfway through an instruction). If you're looking for the code, it's largely in `mm/mmap.c`, and not in any module.

Comment: @Hasturkun please answer do you mean `symbol_name something like mmap` and use sane `offsets` to move further into  mmap function memory start location. So in turn I will be setting break points into mmap function using kprobe. and for knowing which mmap instruction starts and end at which memory offset inside mmap function memory space I have to check mm/mmap? is this what u are saying

Comment: Yes, that sounds about right.

Comment: @Hasturkun I like to ask can I access network device driver buffer in userspace using ioctl and having packets directly in userspace from device driver buffer using `ioctl`. I asked this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65704003/making-kernel-module-and-registering-it-as-pci-device-driver-and-network-device

Comment: You need cooperation from the network driver. As suggested there, take a look at DPDK, or alternately libpcap/tcpdump, depending on what you need (active participant vs passive observer).