# Making Kernel Module and registering it as pci device driver and network device driver and accessing the module's buffer using ioctl. Possible?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, ioctl, userspace

I like to make a kernel module. And inside it I like to register it as pci and network device driver. And using `ioctle` from user space to access the module's buffer(in pci and network driver) and getting buffer. The buffer contains packets received in interrupt handler when packet arrives in my kernel module/device driver and the buffer is global in the module. Means it will not be inside interrupt handler for receiving packets. and in ioctl function implementation inside device driver just returning this buffer to user space

Is it possible?
If not then what solution will achieve the result of accessing packets in buffer inside kernel_module/ethernet_driver from user space application.

Comment: And you cant use promiscuous mode doesn't help with this?

Comment: You can use DPDK to do all packet handling in userspace.

Comment: @stark dpdk sounds good. But can I access the buffer in driver from userspace using ioctl. I think it makes little sense before actually doing it. But please share is this possible what I actually acked in the question. I am asking this since then I dont have to rely  on any api. I really want to learn drivers. So I will like if u please explain is it possible. Just few words.

Comment: Have a look at the uio drivers and see if they do what you want.

Comment: @stark exactly I was thinking of this same thing. What if in ioctl driver implementation I just do "insb" and "outb" and similar io reading functions. Does it make sense. But I will do it inside driver module. Specifically in ioctl function implementation. So everytime user space app use ioctl call it hits driver and read and write happens. Is that u mean? Since realtek ethernet driver also depending on these functions like readl and writel excessively for configuring device. Does it makes sense what I like to do?

Comment: @stark the other way could be what I asked in question. Like this chardev example. I think it's from linux device driver book. Just please let me know can both ways are possible to achieve the result? One way I mentioned in above comment and other which is on this link and initially asked in question for network drivers, so is both ways possible for ethernet PCI drivers too, please let me know?https://linux.die.net/lkmpg/x892.html

Comment: Many ways are possible. Using an ioctl for every read and write might be slow. One way is to allocate a buffer in user space and pass its address to the driver with ioctl.  Driver maps it so it can't move and writes packets and write queue pointer directly so there is no copy.  Userspace can process the packets and move the read queue pointer.

Comment: @stark `Driver maps it so it can't move & writes packets and write queue pointer directly so there is no copy` what do u mean `maps it`? is there any function that driver can use to `map it` and  where exactly write of received packets will happen in driver to user delivered buffer in ioctl .is it inside receive interrupt handler `xxx_poll(struct net_device *dev, int *budget)` of driver so inside this handler I can do `xx_packet=xxx__dequeue_buf(dev)` is this way can it be done?if yes then How received buffer from userspace in driver's ioctl will share the buffer with poll interrupt handler?

Comment: @stark and what exact `xx_packet` struct name is and `___dequeue_buf` func name is that I will  use in poll interrupt handler. In Linux Device Drivers author used `snull_packet`? what if I am working on real driver no loop back

Comment: @stark do u mean use ioctl implementation in driver `static long xx___ioctl(struct file *file, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)` and use `file` in mmap inside xx___ioctl implementation in driver like `mmap(.....file,..)` to map. is `file` type is same as fd?

Comment: @stark can u please take a look at this question. Its related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65749351/in-order-to-write-pci-ethernet-driver-how-to-implement-mmap-in-the-pci-ethernet